# First integrals for topologically conjugate systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the two dynamical systems

System 1: $(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(x(x+1),-y)$

System 2: $(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(x(x+1),-y+4x^3-12x+3)$

which are topologically conjugate, which we can show using the map $\vec{h}(x,y)=(x,y+p(x))$ where $p(x)=2x^2-6x+3$.

First I **need to find the inverse** of $\vec{h}$. Then, given $V(x,y)$ is a first integral of System 2, I **need to find a first integral of System 1**.

I am not really familiar with inverses of vector fields but I think that $\vec{h}^{-1}(x,y)=(x,y-p(x))$. I then tried to show that $V(x,y-p(x))$ was a first integral of system 2 but after taking the time derivative and expanding everything out I ended up with a mess, and not much simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you've written is correct:

1. You can see that your candidate inverse is really an inverse, since the composition of it and your original $h$ gives the identity.
2. There's no algebra required to show what you want—you've done all the hard work already! I recommend using different symbols for your two systems.
3. You got it the wrong sign: you want to translate from 1 to 2, then apply V.

---

Let $(u(t),v(t))$ satisfy the first system: $$(\dot u,\dot v) = \big(u(u+1),-v\big).$$ Then $$(x,y) := (u, v + p(u))$$ satisfies the second system.

Let $V$ being a first integral of System 2. Just writing down the definition gives

$$0 = \frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\big( V(x,y) \big) = \frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\big( V(u,v + p(u)) \big).$$

I.e., $(u,v)↦ V(u,v+p(u))$ is a first integral for System 1.

---